# Visual Studio Code intellisense not showing all properties for string

Tags: angular

Just upgraded my Visual Studio Code to version 1.17.2 (latest), and I'm trying to write an Angular project, and I don't see the basic intellisense for primitive types as illustrated in the following screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V69F.png
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: How did this problem start? Suddenly?

Comment: yes...
meanwhile i've been asked to update vscode and now it works. I'm not sure what just happened. 10x anyway.